# CMake: PCL and Ros Hydro

Tags: pcl, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials

However, I'm not sure what the CMake file needs to look like. I'm getting the following error when compiling:

Could not find a configuration file for package pcl.

Set pcl_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for pcl.
The file will have one of the following names:

```
pclConfig.cmake
pcl-config.cmake
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81741/cmake:-pcl-and-ros-hydro/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2013-09-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like this tutorial is outdated. In hydro, pcl is no more available as a package dependency, but now as a system dependency, meaning the default CMake mechanism described [here at the end of the section](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration#PCL) has to be used.

The [moveit_ros_perception](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/tree/hydro-devel/perception) package can serve as an example (pretty sure you could find others, but that one was the first that crossed my mind).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2013-09-21**:
That helped a lot! Thank you!